# Plotting loss curve

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm working with Pytorch on Mask RCNN. I get training results and losses data, so now I want to plot on graph after each epoch done like this:
[image]

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        # train for one epoch, printing every 10 iterations
        train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
        # update the learning rate
        lr_scheduler.step()
        # evaluate on the test dataset
        evaluate(model, data_loader_test, device=device)
```

In `engine.py` is code for `train_one_epoch`

```
def train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq):
    model.train()
    metric_logger = utils.MetricLogger(delimiter="  ")
    metric_logger.add_meter('lr', utils.SmoothedValue(window_size=1, fmt='{value:.6f}'))
    header = 'Epoch: [{}]'.format(epoch)

    lr_scheduler = None
    if epoch == 0:
        warmup_factor = 1. / 1000
        warmup_iters = min(1000, len(data_loader) - 1)

        lr_scheduler = utils.warmup_lr_scheduler(optimizer, warmup_iters, warmup_factor)

    for images, targets in metric_logger.log_every(data_loader, print_freq, header):
        images = list(image.to(device) for image in images)
        targets = [{k: v.to(device) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]

        loss_dict = model(images, targets)

        losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())

        # reduce losses over all GPUs for logging purposes
        loss_dict_reduced = utils.reduce_dict(loss_dict)
        losses_reduced = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict_reduced.values())

        loss_value = losses_reduced.item()

        if not math.isfinite(loss_value):
            print("Loss is {}, stopping training".format(loss_value))
            print(loss_dict_reduced)
            sys.exit(1)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        losses.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if lr_scheduler is not None:
            lr_scheduler.step()

        metric_logger.update(loss=losses_reduced, **loss_dict_reduced)
        metric_logger.update(lr=optimizer.param_groups[0]["lr"])

    return metric_logger
```

Here this function `train_one_epoch` returns `metric_logger` , so can I use that variable to somehow plot losses and accuracy after each epoch on graph to get something like this:
[image]

Comment: You could try to return either 'losses', 'loss_value' from 'train_one_epoch', insert this into a list, and then plot in matplotlib after your training is finished. Are you familiar with matplotlib?

Comment: Yes I'm. I will try this, tnx.